# React hooks with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this hook:

```
import { userDB } from 'app/services/DBFunctions';
import { auth } from 'Fire';
import { collection, query, limit as fLimit, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { IInvoice, IScheduledEmail, IScheduledInvoice, ITableData } from 'Interface';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

interface Props {
    collectionPath: 'scheduled-invoices' | 'scheduled-emails'
}

const useScheduledFunctions = (props: Props) : IScheduledInvoice[] | IScheduledEmail[] => {
    const {collectionPath} = props
    const [scheduledFunctions, setScheduledFunctions] = useState<IScheduledInvoice[] | IScheduledEmail[]>([])
    const user = auth.currentUser

    useEffect(()=> {
        let queryCollection = query(
            collection(userDB(), collectionPath),
        )
        onSnapshot(queryCollection, (snap: any)=> {
            let scheduledFunctions = snap.docs.map((doc: any)=> doc.data())
            setScheduledFunctions(scheduledFunctions)
        })   
    }, [user, collectionPath])

    return scheduledFunctions
};
```

export default useScheduledFunctions;

But when I call it in a component, the type is either IScheduledInvoice or IScheduledEmail, is there a way to infer the type of the hook based on the collection path?
Currently when I call it, to avoid this conflict, I do this:

```
const scheduledEmails = useScheduledFunctions({collectionPath: 'scheduled-emails'}) as IScheduledEmail[]
```

But I dont like doing this and does not seem like a good solution as I am overriding the type.

Comment: Sounds like you want to make your component [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOyDeAUMsghgDbkQJjAYipxgAWAXMgOQ4LMQAmAVyp8AtKABuGYEhwdkAH07deg4SIgBbOMHKzCAX0KFQkWIhQBJAMo9+Q-hZCTpKfIePho8JMmu3V-ACiWjoE7mAAnlgoAEoQYAJQIAA8ACoAfMgAvMipyBAAHpAgfHj4pBRUNHQMTGxK-vaimtq6cvrIAPy+NipNwa0A2gC6yOx+fcKOzkgjANxGZCA4YMgCOBC9dsIAYgIg1fR4OWn5RRAleOjYOOkAFFiYuOypAJTscQlJaZlZmUQkKDxRIgZAjAwLQhLFbIODZNYbLYBPh7A60I53cpkSjUdG1FjsLiNNQtHSyZD6V4LaGrABG8PWm2J-FRh2WmIqOLZjAJDUm-DETikMnaVKAA)

```js
interface Props {
  collectionPath: 'scheduled-invoices' | 'scheduled-emails'
}

interface IScheduledInvoice {}

interface IScheduledEmail {}

type Return<T> = T extends { collectionPath: 'scheduled-emails' } ? IScheduledEmail[] : IScheduledInvoice[];

const useScheduledFunctions = <T extends Props>(props: T): Return<T> => {
  return []
};

const a = useScheduledFunctions({ collectionPath: 'scheduled-emails' });
const b = useScheduledFunctions({ collectionPath: 'scheduled-invoices' });
```

The pro with that solution is that you can add whatever properties in the `interface Props`. With overloads you will have to implement each possible arguments.

**Personal opinion**: if you have more than two values for `collectionPath` I would go with overloads because you all have to nest ternary extends.

Comment: If there are more values, can I not continue the terniary chain?

Comment: Sure! depends on your personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

You can use overloads to pair certain argument types with return types, then provide an implementation that accepts and returns both.

```
interface Props {
    collectionPath: 'scheduled-invoices' | 'scheduled-emails'
}

function useScheduledFunctions(props: { collectionPath: 'scheduled-invoices' }): IScheduledInvoice[]
function useScheduledFunctions(props: { collectionPath: 'scheduled-emails' }): IScheduledEmail[]
function useScheduledFunctions(props: Props): IScheduledInvoice[] | IScheduledEmail[] {
  return [] // implementation here
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=483#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgygYwBYQCYFcA2aYDsBuA9gJYLQC8UA3lMQSWTKgFxQDOwATnQOZQC+AKFCRYiFBmyoAogFsAhsUxRKNCAqVNWHbrj5DBdYBE4AzeWSgAFToTBtqgqM6gJCmbAmDFCuK-OAkVgByNmQ0LDQAWjoiUgg2YKgAHyhQ8Mlo9UVMRMEDU3RcLx9cKHQ2CHEIqQAxIpLfNgAKMFt7Vho3DwhGvwCgtLCJSNQY+njEgQBKVngM0bw4sgBtAF1BQuLvX3LK6szUeu3Slra7Nk7Xd08d-sCQ4ZqsjVyk-lmxBak5HPXNhp3PZVb5oY59M7tS7WKGfeYjKRLBgQdYpL4ItC-JSoqhOKCcCDAdCcMqogD0ZNosjA2FkEFwwACpSgKAJ+UEgjcuA4tAmZAclAqIIxR0Bp2aXRuvTu-geQ1BY1iyKmH0EFJcUAAegB+DlcnnZJQC4EHUbgu4tSU9PqywbpEVRQ1vGZqykuHVAA)